# force content from left to right without overflowing height

Tags: javascript, css, html

Currently by using left-floated elements I am able to force the content from left to right in a container with a horizontal scroll. (see image 1)

I need the boxes to flow in the order of image 2. So far I cannot find any way to stop the content moving right if it 'hits' the bottom of the div - either it flows outside or superficially stops if using overflow:hidden.

The content is being loaded dynamically

Can this be done with CSS or do I need javascript?

Any help much appreciated

**image1**
[image: image 1]

**image2**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to use `<div>`'s to create columns for the inner content. You can then load your content into the chosen div dynamically using jQuery's `append()` method.

I would recommend using a layout "grid" library to reduce cross browser errors and to make things a little easier with your column layout. The Twitter Bootstrap framework would be great for that: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Here's a link to the grid section: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: many thanks - I have bootstrap loaded on to the project already so I'm going to give this a try

Comment: anytime - if it's successful, please accept this answer (or follow up with more questions).

Comment: for this example I don't think appending will work - the content will either be the width of box 1 (in the diagram) or half of that width, so the div's need to be dynamic enough to handle either a full width or two half width / half height boxes and then move on to the next column. I have tried css3 columns but without the column-span property being valid they are not dynamic enough

Comment: If you're loading the content dynamically, shouldn't you be able to determine the content width beforehand and adjust the <div> width's accordingly when you load the data into them?

Comment: This was fixed using the framework (Ruby on Rails) - I set a div to wrap small blocks differently to the larger blocks, placing a limit of 2 small blocks per div so that small blocks flow down, and then new blocks appear to their right